# ORA-00907: Missing right parenthesis with procedure returning table

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I tried to right a procedure to return a table.
that procedure should return a list with an employee info when `emp_num` parameter equal `SSN` otherwise return list with all employees info.

First I create a record  as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE emp_record IS OBJECT(emp_lname  VARCHAR2(30),
                                        emp_ssn    CHAR(9),
                                        emp_sal    NUMBER(6));
```

Then I create table of type `emp_record` as below:

`CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE emp_table IS TABLE OF emp_record;`

Then I create a procedure `get_employee` with two parameters:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_employee(emp_num IN NUMBER , output_emp OUT emp_table) AS

CURSOR emp_cur IS 
SELECT LNAME,SSN,SALARY
FROM EMPLOYEE 
WHERE NVL((emp_num = SSN),(SSN = SSN));



BEGIN 

    IF NOT (emp_cur%ISOPEN) THEN
    OPEN emp_cur;
    END IF;
    
    LOOP
        FETCH emp_cur BULK COLLECT INTO output_emp;
        EXIT WHEN output_emp.count=0;
    
    CLOSE emp_cur;
    END LOOP;




END;
```

And when I run that code the below error has appear:

**[Warning] ORA-24344: success with compilation error
6/20    PL/SQL: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
4/1     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
(1: 0): Warning: compiled but with compilation errors**

Comment: what did you tried to achieve with `NVL((emp_num = SSN),(SSN = SSN))`?

Comment: By the way, `CHAR` should be `VARCHAR2`.

Answer (score 1):

You have used the alien code here, There is a syntax error:

```
WHERE
NVL(
    (EMP_NUM = SSN),
    (SSN = SSN)
);
```

`NVL` can take two columns/constants as an input parameter, not a boolean.

You want a `WHERE` condition - either `EMP_NUM` is full or if it is not null then it is equal to `SSN` then You need to use something like this:

```
WHERE
NVL(EMP_NUM,SSN) = SSN;
```

or better to use `OR` condition as follows:

```
WHERE EMP_NUM IS NULL OR EMP_NUM = SSN;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm) for [NVL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm) syntax. Based on similarity of syntax I feel you probably want to use [DECODE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm) instead. If so [CASE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm) is the way to go.